# How to install cron

Tags: php, cron

I want to run PHP scripts automatically on a schedule. I learned about CRON recently. But I don't know how to install and use it.

I'm using PHP, CSS, HTML, and running on XAMP apache server on localhost.  How do I install and use Cron?

Comment: The Canonical answer on cron and crontab: http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Answer (score 58):

Do you have a Windows machine or a Linux machine?

Under Windows cron is called 'Scheduled Tasks'. It's located in the Control Panel. You can set several scripts to run at specified times in the control panel. Use the wizard to define the scheduled times. Be sure that PHP is callable in your PATH.

Under Linux you can create a crontab for your current user by typing:

```
crontab -e [username]
```

If this command fails, it's likely that cron is not installed. If you use a Debian based system (Debian, Ubuntu), try the following commands first:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cron
```

If the command runs properly, a text editor will appear. Now you can add command lines to the crontab file. To run something every five minutes:

```
*/5 * * * *  /home/user/test.pl
```

The syntax is basically this:

```
.---------------- minute (0 - 59) 
|  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
|  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
|  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ... 
|  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)  OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat 
|  |  |  |  |
*  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```

Read more about it on the following pages: [Wikipedia: crontab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#crontab_syntax)

Comment: Cron isn't installed by default on all GNU/Linux systems (as crazy as that may sound). You might add a note about how to install a cron (e.g. cronie, vixie-cron...) and how to get it to run on startup (chkconfig on Redhat systems...).

Comment: Good suggestion. Will edit the post a bit :). Although it's difficult to guess without knowing what Unix ;-)

Comment: I had one doubt. Installing CRON in my local windows system will reflect on my hosting web server???. Plz answer me

Comment: What Operating System does your hosting server run on?

Comment: So my local system should be ON at the scheduled time and should connected to internet. Is it so????

Comment: Can u give me your skype or yahoo or gtalk id plz @TheGrandWazoo

Comment: [username] not required it seems in my debian

Comment: Dont forget to use `service cron start` to start it first, otherwise `crontab -e` won't make a change.

Comment: If you get an error `Couldn't find an editor! Set the $EDITOR environment variable to your desired editor.` just install a editor for example nano: `apt-get install nano`

Comment: Super handy cronjob generator/tester see https://crontab.guru/

Answer (score 29):

Install cron on Linux/Unix:

```
apt-get install cron
```

Use cron on Linux/Unix

```
crontab -e
```

See the canonical answer about cron for more details: https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Answer (score 4):

On CentOS/RHEL:

```
yum install cronie
```

Answer (score 3):

Installing Crontab on Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get update
```

We download the crontab file to the root

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/47/c2/d048cbe358acd693b3ee4b330f79d836fb33b716bfaf888f764ee60aee65/crontab-0.20.tar.gz
```

Unzip the file crontab-0.20.tar.gz

```
tar xvfz crontab-0.20.tar.gz
```

Login to a folder crontab-0.20

```
cd crontab-0.20*
```

Installation order

```
python setup.py install
```

See also here:.. http://www.syriatalk.im/crontab.html

Answer (score -3):

Cron is so named "deamon" (same as service under Win).

Most likely cron is already installed on your system (if it is a Linux/Unix system).

Look here: 
http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/startupman/linux_sucron.html

or there
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

for more details.