# Install cron without mail and sql dependencies

Tags: linux, cron, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want to install crontab in Raspberry Pi without mail and sql dependencies ?

I used **apt-get install cron** command to install ,installation was successful, but it also installed mail and sql dependencies. followed [How to install cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802337/how-to-install-cron) to get installation steps.

I need to install crontab only for minimal requirement like sync system time with NTP(Network Time Protocol) upon reboot so that it doesn't required additional dependencies.

How to install crontab without mail and sql dependencies ?

Comment: `cron` only suggests those other packages, they are not Depends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting this directly from [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/250224/how-do-i-get-apt-get-to-ignore-some-dependencies),

> Simple and easy solution: just specify the unwanted packages with an extra - after each of them.

In your case you could, `apt-get install cron mail- sql-`

Replace mail and sql with respective dependencies you don't want to install

You can also use the `-s` option to be extra careful.

From the [man-page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get),

> -s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no-act
>   No action. Perform a simulation of events that would occur but do not actually change the system.