# how to automate running input/output in command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

I have a script that converts json to csv. Is there a cron to automate the following in the command line to run every hour or so? Perhaps adding a number after each run to the output? 
`python3 file.py --input input.json --output output.csv`

Comment: A timestamp in the output file name would be simplest.

Answer (score 0):

"crontab -e" to edit your crontab.
Add this as all one line to the end of your crontab:

```
30 * * * *  /path/to/python3 /path/to/file.py --input /path/to/input.json --output /path/to/output.csv.`date +%Y%m%d%H%M` > /dev/null 2>&1
```

(If you want to get email when there is standard err or out from the process then don't use add the: > /dev/null 2>&1
)

This will run every hour at the 30 minute mark. it will create the output with a date and time stamp appended. If you want to do a sequence number (not date time) then it's a bit more complicated where you need to keep a file that contains the current sequence and update it each time the crontab runs.

You will find that when the date is formatted like this, YEARMONTHDAYHOURMINUTE that the resulting number sorts as a sequence, so for me it usually is better then a sequence number.

if you really need a sequence number instead of a date stamp then write a small shell script that; uses "expr" to add 1 to the number stored in a file then run your process, then update the sequence file:

```
#!/bin/bash

 OLD_SEQ=`cat /path/to/sequence.dat`
 NEW_SEQ=`expr ${OLD_SEQ} + 1`
 python3 file.py --input input.json --output output.csv.${NEW_SEQ}
 echo ${NEW_SEQ} > /path/to/sequence.dat
```

Then you can call this bash script from cron in much the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which system you are using, but there is crontab for your use-case.

You can follow this answer to install it based on your OS [How to install cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802337/how-to-install-cron).

After that your command should be:

```
0  *  *  *  *  python3 file.py --input /<_absolute_path>/input.json --output /<_absolute_path>/output.csv
```

In case of the suffix, is better if you create a script

```
#!/bin/bash
suffix=$(date +"%m%d%H")
python3 file.py --input /<_absolute_path>/input.json --output /<_absolute_path>/output.csv
mv /<_absolute_path>/output.csv "/<_absolute_path>/output_$suffix.csv"
```

And then use it in the cron tab

```
0  *  *  *  * bin/bash /absolute/path/to/your/script
```